# Reset state before setting a new state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, redux-thunk

In my Reactjs app, I'm getting a bunch of success messages from an API with Redux Thunk and rendering them with Material UI 5's `<Snackbar />` component upon fulfilling corresponding actions. I'm accessing these messages with `useSelector`.

*For example:* A user logs in and sees the message `Login Successful` - Adds a product to their cart and sees the message `Product added successfully` - Logs out and sees the messages `Logout Successful`.

I'm setting the corresponding success messages like so (*Two reducers are involved: `users` and `carts`*):

```
  // Success message state
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");

  // Users state
  const userMessage = useSelector(selectUserMessage);

  // Cart state
  const cartMessage = useSelector(selectCartMessage);

  // User success message
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userMessage?.message) {
      setSuccessMessage(userMessage.message);
    }
  }, [userMessage]);

  // Cart success message
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cartMessage?.message) {
      setSuccessMessage(cartMessage.message);
    }
  }, [cartMessage]);

  // Show snackbar if all or one components succeeds
  // login, logout, and cart message states
  useEffect(() => {
      if (
        loggedInState ||
        loggedOutState ||
        cartMessage?.message
      ) {
        setOpen(true);
      }
  }, [
    loggedInState,
    loggedOutState,
    cartMessage,
  ]);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center" }}
    >
      <Alert severity="success" sx={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        {successMessage ? successMessage : "Process Successful!"}
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
```

***The problem arises in this scenario:*** A user logs in and sees the successful login message - adds a product to their cart and sees the product added message - **logs out and for a moment sees the message: `Product added successfully` instead of `Logout successful` and after a moment sees `Logout successful`.**

**What I want to do is to reset the `cartMessage` and/or even `userMessage` (or even better, reset the `successMessage`) before it gets to set the success message state to a new one so that the previous state gets cleared.**

*Things I have tried to no avail:*

- `setSuccessMessage = ""` before setting a new one
- Clear `cartMessage` state upon logout with a `clearCartMessage` action dispatched either in the logout function or in user's success message `useEffect` before setting the message.

Is there any way I can fix this?